# Google Glass Multiple Embedded Layout using CardScrollView

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

What im doing is I'm inserting card using CardScrollView in google glass using an EMBEDDED LAYOUT because the table layout is not yet available in card builder. Let's assume that every table has 1 textView. What's happening is when I insert 1-3 layout, there's is no any error but when i inserted the 4th layout it gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException in this line.

```
    tv4.setText('Value for table 4');
```

This is my code:

**NOTE: I have atleast 5 TextView in each table. make it simple here.**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    createCards();

    mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
    mAdapter = new ExampleCardScrollAdapter();
    mCardScrollView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mCardScrollView.activate();
    setContentView(mCardScrollView);


    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);



    tv1.setText('Value for table 1');
    tv2.setText('Value for table 2');
    tv3.setText('Value for table 3');
    tv4.setText('Value for table 4');
    }

private void createCards(){
    mCards = new ArrayList<CardBuilder>();

     mCards.add(new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.EMBED_INSIDE)
    .setEmbeddedLayout(R.layout.activity_layout1)
    .setFootnote("TABLE 1"));

     mCards.add(new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.EMBED_INSIDE)
    .setEmbeddedLayout(R.layout.activity_layout2)
    .setFootnote("TABLE 2"));

     mCards.add(new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.EMBED_INSIDE)
    .setEmbeddedLayout(R.layout.activity_layout3)
    .setFootnote("TABLE 3"));

     mCards.add(new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.EMBED_INSIDE)
    .setEmbeddedLayout(R.layout.activity_layout4)
    .setFootnote("TABLE 4")); 
    }

private class ExampleCardScrollAdapter extends CardScrollAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Object item) {
        return mCards.indexOf(item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mCards.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return CardBuilder.getViewTypeCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        return mCards.get(position).getItemViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mCards.get(position).getView(convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

activity_layout1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/textViewTitle1"
        android:textColor="@color/muted" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

activity_layout2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/textViewTitle2"
        android:textColor="@color/muted" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

activity_layout3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/textViewTitle4"
        android:textColor="@color/muted" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

activity_layout4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/textViewTitle4"
        android:textColor="@color/muted" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Adapter

```
    private class ExampleCardScrollAdapter extends CardScrollAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Object item) {
        return mCards.indexOf(item);
    } 

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCards.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mCards.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return CardBuilder.getViewTypeCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        return mCards.get(position).getItemViewType();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mCards.get(position).getView(convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Please help because I'm stuck in here for days. Thank you!

Comment: Could you also add the various layout XML files?

Answer (score 2):

There a few things that are wrong with the way you are setting text for your various views.

#### Why it crashes

The reason it crashes is because the `CardScrollView` currently retrieves 5 `Views` at a time, the current one and 2 for either directions. Since the `CardScrollView` starts at position 0, only `Views` at position 0, 1, and 2 are loaded: this makes setting text for `tv1`, `tv2` and `tv2` possible as they are in the view hierarchy.

Since `tv4` has not been added, trying to retrieve the `View` will return `null`.

#### How to fix this

Since each card in your `CardScrollView` has the same layout, you don't need to create 4 separate ones and initiliaze them in `onCreate`. You should instead inflate the `Views` when needed and set the text or other data appropriately.

`card_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/textViewTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/muted" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

`Adapter`:

```
private class ExampleCardScrollAdapter extends CardScrollAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Object item) {
        return mTexts.indexOf(item);
    } 

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTexts.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mTexts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        return CardBuilder.EMBED_INSIDE.ordinal();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.EMBED_INSIDE)
                .setEmbeddedLayout(R.layout.card_layout)
                .setFootnote("TABLE " + position)
                .getView(convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setText(mTexts.get(position));
        return view;        
    }
}
```

Then, in your `Activity`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    createTexts();

    mCardScrollView = new CardScrollView(this);
    mAdapter = new ExampleCardScrollAdapter();
    mCardScrollView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mCardScrollView.activate();  // This should be moved in onResume.
    setContentView(mCardScrollView);
}

private void createTexts(){
    mTexts = new ArrayList<String>();

    mTexts.add("Value for table 1");
    mTexts.add("Value for table 2");
    mTexts.add("Value for table 3");
    mTexts.add("Value for table 4");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response sir, and its my fault giving a 1 layout example since I actually need different layouts. i have different number of columns and table rows each layout. How can I do this?

Comment: Also when i tried your code it gives me an error here return CardBuilder.EMBED_INSIDE.ordinal(); and         View view = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.EMBED_INSIDE)